# Saving to database using EF Database First - Default value issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to MVC and EF and have a problem when updating a row in the SQL database, which has a default value set on the column.

I have set'StoredGeneratedPattern' to 'Computed' on the property (edmx) in order to invoke the default value in the database when inserting a new record via EF DB 1st.This works fine.

However, When I update an object that has this property set to 'computed', the default value in the database is still being set. I assumed that as this property now has a value and is not null, the default value wouldn't be invoked.

I have updated the record directly via SSMS and this works as expected.

I did originally set a default value via code in the person model, but this code is removed when I refreshed the edmx, which is why I'm using the StoredGeneratedPattern.

I'd be grateful if somebody could advise me on how to correct this.
[image]

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Person person = db.People.Find(id);
        if (person == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "Description", person.LocationID);
        ViewBag.StatusID = new SelectList(db.Status, "StatusID", "Description", person.StatusID);
        ViewBag.TitleID = new SelectList(db.Titles, "TitleID", "Description", person.TitleID);
        ViewBag.PersonID = new SelectList(db.Volunteers, "VolunteerID", "VolunteerID", person.PersonID);
        return View(person);
    }

    // POST: People/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "PersonID,TitleID,Forename,MiddleName,Surname,DateofBirth,Gender,LocationID,StatusID,LastUpdated,Archived")] Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "Description", person.LocationID);
        ViewBag.StatusID = new SelectList(db.Status, "StatusID", "Description", person.StatusID);
        ViewBag.TitleID = new SelectList(db.Titles, "TitleID", "Description", person.TitleID);
        ViewBag.PersonID = new SelectList(db.Volunteers, "VolunteerID", "VolunteerID", person.PersonID);
        return View(person);
    }
```

Comment: can you please post the code instead of image?

Comment: I've uploaded the controller code for the edit routine. LastUpdated and Archived have default values  in the SQL database.

Comment: Computed means that there is no column in the database and the value is computed from the select statement instead. This causes the value not being saved, because EF thinks there is no column to save the value. So for your needs _computed_ seems to be the wrong option. I'm not sure but maybe better would be to set a default value in the model and do not set any attribute

Comment: I did originally set it in the model constructor but the code disappears when I refresh the edmx. Similarly, when I add a data type above a property, this is also removed when I perform a refresh.  e.g.     [DataType(DataType.Password)] - anyway, thanks for your explanation, this makes sense to me. I have since removed the computed value, and set the default property in the edmx, and this seems to work!